# How to concat two or more data frames with different columns names in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have hundreds csv files and I need join it to one file. I have it all load as pandas dataframes. Sample dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['e1','e1','e1'],'x':[4,5,6],'y':[7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['e2','e2','e2'],'x':[13,14,15],'y':[16,17,18], 'z':[100,101,102]})
```

I need this output:

```
    a   x   y    z
0  e1   4   7     
1  e1   5   8     
2  e1   6   9     
3  e2  13  16  100
4  e2  14  17  101
5  e2  15  18  102
```

or

```
    a   x   y    z
0  e1   4   7   na
1  e1   5   8   na
2  e1   6   9   na
3  e2  13  16  100
4  e2  14  17  101
5  e2  15  18  102
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

EDIT:

I have cca 500 csv files, this is my code to make one file from them:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:/Users/Miro/data hist'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, sep='delimiter', header=None)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

frame.to_csv( "full.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['e1','e1','e1'],'x':[4,5,6],'y':[7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['e2','e2','e2'],'x':[13,14,15],'y':[16,17,18], 'z':[100,101,102]})
newdf = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

```
    a   x   y      z
0  e1   4   7    NaN
1  e1   5   8    NaN
2  e1   6   9    NaN
3  e2  13  16  100.0
4  e2  14  17  101.0
5  e2  15  18  102.0
```

Or if you really want `na` values rather than `NaN` you could do

```
newdf = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True).fillna("na")
```

```
    a   x   y    z
0  e1   4   7   na
1  e1   5   8   na
2  e1   6   9   na
3  e2  13  16  100
4  e2  14  17  101
5  e2  15  18  102
```

To get this to work in your edited question:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:/Users/Miro/data hist'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, sep='delimiter', header=None)
    li = li.append(df, ignore_index=True)


li.to_csv( "full.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Your solution is function, but I dont know how use it with mi code. Pls can you look at my updated question?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Could you check if it's working and if so, mark my answer as accepted?